# Jenkins error: Can't find Xvfb installation

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I defined [Xvfb installation](http://prntscr.com/issnbl)  on Jenkins according to these instructions: [https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin).

> *Access Manage Jenkins >> Global Tool Configuration*. In Section *Xvfb installation*, put name and fill the field *Directory in which to find Xvfb executable* with `/usr/bin`.

But this error appears:

> Home path does not contain Xfvb executable: /usr/bin and build fails with following error: [No Xvfb installations defined, please define one in the configuration. Once defined you’ll need to choose one under Advanced options for Xvfb plugin job settings and save job configuration.](http://prntscr.com/issomt)

I have Xvfb plugin version 1.1.3

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same issue while setting up the jenkins
Manually I had  to set the path like below

export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/Xvfb"

And then adding /usr/bin in Global Tool Configuration under "Directory in which to find Xvfb executable " solved the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the correct answer... for me anyway. Add `/user/bin` as the path to Xvfb and then add `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/Xvfb"` to your job's shell commands... pretty dumb but it works!